# Zf2 - I am not able to define the form as shared one using its name as well as alias

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element

I am working on ZendFramework 2. I have a form which I want to be used as a shared instance. But the `shared` key only accepts the actual class rather then the name allocated to it. Sharing some of the code snippet for better understanding of my problem:

SampleForm.php

```
namespace MyProject\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class Sampleform extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('sampelname');
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the form elements
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(
            [
                'type' => 'Text',
                'name' => 'name',
                'options' => [
                    'label' => 'Enter your name',
                ]
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Defining the `SampleForm` in `Module.php`:

```
namespace MyProject;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\FormElementProviderInterface;
use MyProject\Form\SampleForm;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface, FormElementProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormElementConfig()
    {
        return [
            'invokables' => [
                'MyProject\Form\SharedSampleForm' => SampleForm::class,
            ],
            'aliases' => [
                'sharedSampleForm' => 'MyProject\Form\SharedSampleForm'
            ],
            'shared' => [
                'MyProject\Form\SharedSampleForm' => true
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

It throws me the error like:
`Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\Form\FormElementManager\FormElementManagerV2Polyfill::setShared: A service by the name "MyProject\Form\SharedSampleForm" was not found and could not be marked as shared`

But it works as expected when I define my `getFormElementConfig` in `Module.php` as follows:

```
public function getFormElementConfig()
{
    return [
        'invokables' => [
            'MyProject\Form\SharedSampleForm' => SampleForm::class,
        ],
        'aliases' => [
            'sharedSampleForm' => 'MyProject\Form\SharedSampleForm'
        ],
        'shared' => [
            SampleForm::class => true
        ]
    ];
}
```

i.e. In the `shared` key I provide the reference to the actual Form class name.

If the same definitions are defined under `getServiceConfig()` then it works as expected without throwing any such error.

Can some one please suggest/help me out how can I be able to use the service name in the `shared` for forms then providing the actual class reference?

Answer (score -1):

`getFormElementConfig()` is used for defining **Form Element**. Not used for defining **Form** as service. If you wanna define this form as `Service`, you should define it under `getServiceConfig()`.

Another tips, if you have make an alias, just define the `Service` name using it's class name.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return [
        'invokables' => [
            SampleForm::class => SampleForm::class,
        ],
        'aliases' => [
            'sharedSampleForm' => SampleForm::class
        ],
        'shared' => [
            SampleForm::class => true
        ]
    ];
}
```

You can call the Form using the alias name like this `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('sharedSampleForm');`

Comment: Well as far as I know, its not correct convention of defining the form in the `getServiceConfig()` because form definitions should always go under `getFormElementConfig()`. Thank you for your response, but I do not think it as a correct solution. And regarding the second suggestion, I want some specific name for the form while defining it, so I can not define its name as the same as the class name.

Comment: please check this, you will see `getFormElementConfig()` used to define custom form element, not defining form https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements

Comment: I agree with you that `getFormElementConfig()` is for defining the custom element. But if you notice Form class (`Zend\Form\Form`) it itself is extending the `Element` internally through `Fieldset`, so as a result our form class itself is a custom element. And hence it should be defined within `getFormElementConfig()`.

Comment: `Zend\Form\Form` is not extend from `Element`. Sample of `Element` is `Zend\Form\Element\Email', element itself is added to form like this `$form->add(array(
     'type' => 'Email',
     'name' => 'email'
));`.

Comment: Can you please check once `Zend\Form\Form`, when I see the source of it (https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Form.php), it extends the `Fieldset`, and when you check the source of `Fieldset` (https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Fieldset.php) it extends the `Element` . So eventually its the same pattern like what you are providing as an example, i.e. `email` extends `Element` while in my case `SampleForm` extends `Form` extends `Fieldset` extends `Element`.

Comment: yes `Zend\Form\Form` extends from `Fieldset` extends from `Element`. But `Zend\Form\Form` use interface from `FormInterface` and `Element` use interface from `InputProviderInterface` that caused they are not same. And `getFormElementService` is purpised for Element not form, like example in ZF documentation

Comment: @DollyAswin I'm sorry, but you're wrong, the form element manager can most definitely be used for forms, in some cases it's the *only* reasonable way to use them properly. If you want a documentation example, see the advanced section here -> https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-form/advanced/ Specifically, if you read the section on custom elements, one of the two 'gotchas' to be aware of says `The second catch is that you must not directly instantiate your form class, but rather get an instance of it through Zend\Form\FormElementManager:`

Comment: Wrong. All form elements, including forms, should be registered with the `FormElementManager`.